# Redefinition of Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bluebird, es6-promise

Promise is now a global reserved word in es6 and linters throw a error. So what are the pitfalls of doing this

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
```

or should i do

```
var BluebirdPromise = require("bluebird");
```

Comment: Many of us do that. There's no problem. You're just using a faster implementation, that's all. But note that you may use more and more promises given by various libraries, so this is a very limited replacement (there are discussions in the node world about ways to define a library as a global promise provider).

Comment: From a module approach it doesn't matter because you aren't overwriting globals unless you explicitly do: `global.Promise = ` ...

Comment: `Promise` is not a reserved word.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it now. Anyone?

Comment: The main downside being that it'll be confusing if you use `Promise` and forget to `require` it so you use the global instead of Bluebird. I usually recommend `var Bluebird = require('bluebird');`

Comment: @Bergi all linters throw error

Comment: @aWebDeveloper It's not a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_6) though. It's a poor choice for an identifier because it causes confusion & ambiguity, but it's not illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a problem to redeclaring promise as long as it's not global. But second one is a better approach

> Many of us do that. There's no problem. You're just using a faster
>   implementation, that's all. But note that you may use more and more
>   promises given by various libraries, so this is a very limited
>   replacement (there are discussions in the node world about ways to
>   define a library as a global promise provider). – Denys Séguret

Answer (score 2):

Simply put these lines inside `.jshintrc`

```
{
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "predef": [ "-Promise" ]
}
```

Comment: {"predef": [ "-Promise" ]} did the job for me :)